# Удаление нескольких строк в таблице одним запросом. MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Как удалить несколько строк в таблице одним запросом?

Comment: DELETE FROM table_name WHERE (условие, которому удовлетворяют несколько строк)

Comment: Мне нужно, что бы записи удалялись по выбору с чекбокса, смог реализировать только одиночное удаление, но вот реализировать удаление сразу нескольких не удается...

Comment: Покажите как реализовано одиночное удаление и объясните чем вам не понятен совет @Etki

Comment: Если передаешь id отмеченной записи, то можно так DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id IN (id1, id2, .., id_N)

Answer (score 2):

Объясняю как гуглить: множественный чекбокс,
прием данных post запросом с этого чекбокса,
составление запроса как указал batazor

Comment: Спасибо, уже сам решил проблему... Спасибо большое batazor...